# Firebase database won't store (write) data in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The fields are not being written to firebase data base when the action button is pressed. I have the database linked to the app and all the pods installed. It builds correctly but when i run the simulation, the button segues to the next view controller but the data isn't saved to firebase.

```
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    //Validate the fields
    let error = validateFields()

    if error != nil {

        //There's something wrong with the fields, show error message
        showErrorUser("Make sure all fields filled out correctly.")

    } else {

        //Create clean version of data
        let firstName = firstNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let lastName = lastNameTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let address = addressTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let city = cityTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let state = stateTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let zipCode = zipCodeTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        //Create the user
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in

            //Check for errors
            if err != nil {

                //There was an error creating the user
                self.showErrorUser("Error creating user")
            } else {

                //User was created successfully, store user information
                let db = Firestore.firestore()

                db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["firstName":firstName, "lastName":lastName, "address":address, "city":city, "state":state, "zipCode":zipCode, "email":email, "password":password, "uid": result!.user.uid ]) { (error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        self.showErrorUser("Error saving user data")
                    }

                }

                //Transition to home screen
                self.transitionToHome()

            }
```

Comment: You've tagged the question with `firebase-realtime-data`, but your code is calling the Cloud Firestore API. The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two completely separate databases, so make sure that you're also looking at [Cloud Firestore in the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/firestore/data).

Comment: Please note that Firebase is asynchronous and this line `self.transitionToHome()` will execute before the data is written to Firebase. That may be ok in this case but we don't know what that function does. Also, note that users are typically stored in a */users* node with the documentId being the users uid. In this case it's being stored in a field which means every time you want that data, you'll have to query for it (slower) instead of accessing it directly (way faster) at */users/uid*